# Change Hide/Visible with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hide

I'm using Angular(1.6.4), and I'm lost as how to change a component from being visible to invisible and vice-versa.  For instance, I have this component where I would like to programmatically modify its visibility:

When I go looking for documentation, I see that there is an "ng-hide" command, but that's for the old version of Angular and I'm not able to find how it's done in the current version (1.6.4)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you've found that `ng-hide` is only for old versions of Angular.
[ngShow](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and [ngHide](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directives work fine in version 1.6.4, so feel free to use them for your needs.